# Graphics micro-stutter

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I experience some issues with my fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 as the graphics stutter for a second or what and then consumes. The audio is running in the background, but the screen freezes for a short time. I have these issues when I'm using graphical processes, like video playback in Google Chrome. But also when I try to run Dolphin Emulator.

My graphics card is an hybrid of the Intel® HD Graphics 520 and the AMD Radeon R7 M365X. I am aware that there are no drivers for this graphics card.
Does someone know what I have to do?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem on nearly the same hardware. Mine is not a hybrid though, only Intel(R) HD Graphics 520. It's very annoying so I hope this can get get fixed.